# Entering the review queue with no close votes?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, review, closing

This morning I found 13 questions in the "Close Votes" review queue. Of them, four I considered odd - they were not the standard questions from that queue, so I clicked on the "link" to see how many close votes they had. And they each had...none$^{[1]}$.

> What is going on here? Can questions enter the review queue with no close votes?

$^{[1]}$ Well, okay, one had one, but it obtained that vote when in the review queue. So it *entered* the review queue with, apparently, no votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a user (without the vote-to-close privilege) flags a question using one of the canned close reasons, the question will be placed in the Close Votes review queue (see [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169588/214632)). Since that user cannot vote to close, the question will enter in the queue without any close votes.

(If a user *with* the vote-to-close privilege flags a question using one of the canned close reasons, the flag is just converted into a close vote.)

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.